# How to split a string in a pandas dataframe into bigrams that can then exploded into new rows?

Tags: python, pandas, nltk, tf-idf, cosine-similarity

I have a database of name records that I'm trying to create bigrams for and have the bigrams turned into new rows in the dataframe. The reason I'm doing this is because there are certain records that contain multiple names and also some can have different orders for the same name. My ultimate goal is to look for duplicates and create one ultimate record for each unique individual. I plan to use TF-IDF and cosine similarity on the results of this. Below is an example of what I'm trying to do.

Current:
[image]

Goal:
[image]

Comment: do all names have two parts?

Comment: It is possible that a record could just be a first or last name or have a last name that's two words separated by a hyphen.

Comment: Check the updated answer it will solve your problem :)

Comment: @Pygirl Awesome, thank you!

Comment: If the data is `John Doe Mike Steve Johnson`, it will result in `John Doe`, `Mike Steve` and `Johnson`. Is that OK?

Comment: I didn't get it.

Comment: The method worked, but didn't keep the original ID.

Comment: What do you mean by original ID?  I am getting the same result as goal

Comment: Did you try edited 2nd part solution?

Comment: I think the issue is some records in the database have been deleted so the IDs in my dataframe are not necessarily consecutive numbers.

Comment: Yeah that could be the reason because for the posted data It works fine and give the same result.  Btw other answerer and mine 2nd answer are same. Only difference with the syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
bigrams = [[id, ' '.join(b)] for id, l in zip(df['ID'].tolist(), df['Name'].tolist()) for b in zip(l.split(" ")[:-1], l.split(" ")[1:])]
bigrams_df = pd.DataFrame(bigrams, columns = ['ID','Name'])
```

Comment: This works well but is there a way to keep the ID?

Comment: If there is a record with just a last name like `Johnson`, is there a way to keep those instances in?

Answer (score 3):

try using `zip`,`apply` and `explode`:

```
df.Name = df.Name.str.split() 

df.Name.apply(lambda x: tuple(zip(x,x[1:]))).explode().map(lambda x: f"{x[0]} {x[1]}")
```

Or

**using list comprehension:**

```
df2 = pd.Series([ f"{a} {b}" for val in df.Name for (a,b) in (zip(val,val[1:]))])
```

---

```
0         John Doe
1         John Doe
1         Doe Mike
1       Mike Smith
2         John Doe
2         Doe Mike
2       Mike Smith
2      Smith Steve
2    Steve Johnson
3       Smith Mike
3          Mike J.
3           J. Doe
3      Doe Johnson
3    Johnson Steve
4         Steve J.
4             J. M
4          M Smith
Name: Name, dtype: object
```

**edit:**

2nd part:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame([ [idx+1, f"{a} {b}"] for idx,val in enumerate(df.Name) for (a,b) in (zip(val,val[1:]))], columns=['ID', 'Names'])
```

Comment: I'm getting an error `float object isn't subscriptable` for the first option. The second option looks good, except I'm, losing the original ID for each record.